# Change image linkbutton on click

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, events, linkbutton

Having this piece of code:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="ChangeImage_Click" >
  <img src="imagethatshouldbechanged" />
</asp:LinkButton>
```

And this:

```
protected void ChangeImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Code here
}
```

How do I change the image when I click the linkbutton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make img `runat="server"` and assign id to it to access in `ChangeImage_Click` or use [asp:Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `img`

HTML

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="ChangeImage_Click" >
  <img id="img1" runat="server" src="imagethatshouldbechanged" />
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Code bahind

```
protected void ChangeImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    img1.Src = "url";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="ChangeImage_Click" >
  <img runat="server" id="myImage" src="imagethatshouldbechanged" />
</asp:LinkButton>

protected void ChangeImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   myImage.Src="YourImagePath";//Like App/app1/image1.jpeg
}
```